# In React, the localstorage.getItem return null

Tags: reactjs, frontend, local-storage, okta

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const obj = { a: "xxx", b: "yyy" }
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

client.js:

```js
let settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'));
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
    issuer: settings['a'],
    clientId: settings['b'],
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback',
    logoutUrl: window.location.origin + '/login',
    // pkce: false
});
```

I import the client in App, It seem like the localStorage should setItem before the client.js run. But I got null for localStrorage.getItem('obj'). Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Use useEffect()

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
 
const App=()=>{

useEffect(()=>{
const obj = { a: "xxx", b: "yyy" }
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
},[])

return(
     <div></div>
)
}
```